# Having problem deploying github repository to heoku

Tags: swift, mongodb, heroku, vapor

Trying to deploy this repository to heoku using the deploy to heroku button.
https://github.com/abdulkhaliq92/FaxServer
I have a valid app.json file:

```
{
    "name": "FaxServer",
    "scripts": {},
    "env": {},
    "formation": {},
    "addons": [],
    "buildpacks": [
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/kylef/heroku-buildpack-swift"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following error occurs while deploying.

```
Downloading swift-corelibs-libdispatch (swift-4.1-RELEASE)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
     0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1729k
Building Swift
This may take a very long time...
Building Swift failed
Check out the logfile for more information: /app/tmp/cache/swiftenv/tmp/swiftenv-build-4.1/swiftenv-build.20190214170118.272.log
You can inspect or delete the working tree at: /app/tmp/cache/swiftenv/tmp/swiftenv-build-4.1
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Swift app.
 !     Push failed
```

EDIT:
Still getting the same error.
Here is the Package.swift file : https://github.com/abdulkhaliq92/FaxServer/blob/master/Package.swift

Comment: Use `https://github.com/vapor-community/heroku-buildpack` as the buildpack instead

Comment: You should update your original question with that error message, instead of adding it to a comment. Also, post your Package.swift

Comment: updated question, Please have a look.

Comment: Which is the content of `/app/tmp/cache/swiftenv/tmp/swiftenv-build-4.1/swiftenv-build.20190214170118.272.log` ?